# Kaggle and R Programming - cannot read csv file, path related issue

Tags: r, csv, kaggle

I am new to data analysis, R, and Kaggle. I am in the process of uploading my first dataset, "Bellabeat case study" to Kaggle and having issues reading in the csv files within the directory in Kaggle.

What I've done:

1. I completed my analysis in Kaggle and saved the completed file.
2. Created a new notebook and uploaded that file successfully.
3. installed tidyverse package and loaded library. This was successful.
4. Read in csv file - I cannot read my csv files into Kaggle anymore, even though I ran all the code in Kaggle prior to creating this new notebook.
5. I tried a multitude of different paths to get my files with no success. (noted below)

Can someone please advise me on what I'm doing wrong?

Here is some code I used to try and figure out the issue:

```
# List all files in the directory
#files <- list.files("/kaggle/input/fitabase-data-4-12-16-5-12-16")

# Print the list of files
#print(files)

output: character(0)

# Get working directory
#getwd()

output: '/kaggle/working'

# Full path to the file
#file_path <- "/kaggle/input/fitabase-data-4-12-16-5-12-16/dailyActivity_merged.csv"

# Print the full file path
#print(file_path)

output: [1] "/kaggle/input/fitabase-data-4-12-16-5-12-16/dailyActivity_merged.csv"

# Set working directory does not work
# setwd("/kaggle/input/fitabase-data-4-12-16-5-12-16")
```

Path's I've tried:

```
# activity_day <- read.csv(file = "/kaggle/input/fitabase-data-4-12-16-5-12-16/dailyActivity_merged.csv")

# activity_day <- read.csv(file = "dailyActivity_merged.csv")

# activity_day <- read.csv("/kaggle/input/fitabase-data-4-12-16-5-12-16/dailyActivity_merged.csv")
```

Error I keep getting:

```
#error: Warning message in file(file, "rt"):
#“cannot open file '/kaggle/input/fitabase-data-4-12-16-5-12-16/dailyActivity_merged.csv': No such file or directory”
#Error in file(file, "rt"): cannot open the connection
#Traceback:
```

Comment: `getwd()` returns "kaggle/working"; your code operates on "kaggle/input". If that solved the issue, please consider deleting it as it's purely typo-related.

Comment: Following up on the comment from I_O you could try `read.csv("../input/fitabase-data-4-12-16-5-12-16/dailyActivity_merged.csv")`

Comment: I listed that code on purpose to show what is working directory. It's not a typo and I agree, you're right on the path issue. That's why I added that code, to show the path situation. I don't know how to resolve this issue in Kaggle, as I cannot use setwd(). Also, I have been reading these into Kaggle all during my analysis phase with no issue. Since I created the new notebook and uploaded my existing file, I can no longer read csv's. I'm stuck. Any more advice? I appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow, I apologize for the inconsistencies in comments.

Comment: Have you tried `read.csv("../input/fitabase-data-4-12-16-5-12-16/dailyActivity_merged.csv")`?

Comment: Yes, I tried more paths. I started over by creating a new notebook. I don't think it's the answer, but I don't know what else to try.

Comment: I couldn't resolve the path issue in Kaggle. Troubleshooting techniques: open the file and data is fine. Downloaded the file and opened in excel and file was fine. The code to check for file was showed it in the accurate directory showed. I created a new directory for my csv files and it worked. Resolved